# drop shadow to spread full width of element

Tags: html, css

How do I get a drop shadow to spread the full width of an element. This is what I have right now but I'm it's falling short of spreading horizontally across the element.
As you can see at the right and left of the image the shadow is inset I need it to span the entire width.

```
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your negative spread-radius is causing that. Change the -6px to some positive value:

```
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 6px black;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t3evU/)**

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow):

> Positive values will cause the shadow
>   to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to
>   shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will be the same
>   size as the element).

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the -6px have it at 0px, also dont forget about other browsers.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 0 #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 0 #000000;
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 0 #000000;
```